# Inequality similar to Schwarz-Pick

Tags: complex-analysis

I saw this posted on another forum with no background or additional information:

Let $f:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$ be analytical in the unit disk, then the following holds for any two points $z_1, z_2 \in\mathbb{D}$:
$$\frac{(1-|f(z_1)|^2)(1-|f(z_2)|^2)}{(1-|z_1|^2)(1-|z_2|^2)}\ge \frac{|f(z_1)-f(z_2)|^2}{|z_1-z_2|^2}$$

This looks like, and is exactly equal to in the limit $z_1\to z_2$, the Schwarz-Pick inequality, but I don't know if it is a weaker or stronger version (or even true). I'd appreciate any information about this inequality and a proof if it is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if the inequality holds for some $f$, then it holds for $\psi\circ f\circ \varphi$, where $\psi,\varphi$ are automorphisms of the disk (that it holds for $f\circ\varphi$ is obvious since you can just change variables $w=\varphi(z)$, the case of $\psi\circ f$ is a little more tedious, but at the end of the day a simple computation).

The above means that we can restrict attention to the case $z_1=0$, and $f(0)=0$, and in this case, after some algebra, we see that the inequality is equivalent to $|f(z)|\leq |z|$, and this is Schwarz Lemma.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize the inequality is invariant under automorphisms. I think by the same logic it can be shown that it is weaker than Schwarz-Pick.